# ¿ Alguien me explica este ejercicio?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio:

> Considera que estás desarrollando un programa Java donde trabajas con
>   la superclase Profesor y la subclase ProfessorEmerit. Crea código para
>   a estas clases que cumpla los requisitos que indicamos.
>
> Como atributos de la superclase tendremos nombre (String), edad (int)
>   y anysConsolidats (int) declarados como protected.
>
> En la subclase se trabajará con el campo adicional aysEmerit declarado
>   como private.
>
> Un método de la subclase será double obtenirSalariBase () que obtendrá
>   el salario base como (925 + anysConsolidats * 33.25 + 47.80 *
>   anysEmerit).
>
> Intenta acceder directamente al campo aynsConsolidats desde la
>   subclase (como si fuera un campo más de la subclase) para implementar
>   este método. Es posible sin utilizar una invocación a super ni un
>   método get? ¿Qué pasa si el atributo a la superclase el declaras
>   private?

Tengo hecho esta parte del código:

Professor:

```
//Atributos
    protected String nom;
    protected int edat, anys_consolidats;
```

ProfessorEmerit:

```
package Practica3_EX2;

public class ProfessorEmerit extends Professor{
    //Atributos
    private int anyEmerit;

    //Metodos especiales
    public double obtenirSalariBase(double salariBase) {
        return salariBase=(925+anys_consolidats*33.25+47.80*anyEmerit);
    }
}
```

Pero me surgen muchas dudas, por ejemplo, el método obtenirSalariBase() que hay que hacer en la subclase, tengo que crear una variable que se llame salario base ?. Algo así :

```
//Metodos especiales
    public double obtenirSalariBase(double salariBase) {
        return salariBase=(925+anys_consolidats*33.25+47.80*anyEmerit);
    }
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. ¿tienes algún error con este código o cuáles son tus dudas específicas?

Comment: Mi duda está en que no sé como hacer el método obtenirSalariBase(), tengo que crear una variable que se llame salariBase?

Comment: No hace falta que lo asignes a una variable, puedes hacer directamente `return (925+anys_consolidats*33.25+47.80*anyEmerit);`

Comment: tienes que tratar de seguir las indicaciones que te proveen, en particular no te piden crear ningun atributo `salariBase` solo te indican como implementar el metodo. Si para implementarlo decides usar variables locales es decision tuya como programador.

Comment: Ah, ya lo entiendo, muchas gracias !

Comment: En ambos casos te va a funcionar, pero como programador siempre vale la pena preguntarse si añadir cosas a tu código *realmente* es necesario. En este caso la variable no aporta nada porque vas a devolver inmediatamente, por lo que quitarla es una buena opción.

Comment: En tu código quizá lo más importante no es si declarar una variable para luego retornarla y nada más. Como te han dicho, no vale la pena declararla, aunque si lo haces tampoco va a ser una catástrofe. Lo que sí está limitando bastante tu clase son los valores fijos que tienes en ella, lo que la hace una clase bastante pobre, dependiente de esos valores. Cuando los mismos cambien vas a tener que ir a ese método a modificarlo. Y no imigenemos que haya un cambio *temporal* de esos valores determinado por elementos circunstanciales... Sé que es un ejercicio, pero esa clase debería tener al...

Comment: ... menos un `setter` donde se establezcan esos valores fijos... O dos constructores en uno de los cuales se reciban esos valores. Una clase concebida así es muy pobre, pues suele ocurrir que los valores evolucionen con el tiempo. Dejo este comentario solo para subrayar que cuando creas una clase es con la idea de que la misma se adapte a evoluciones futuras.